# Semantic-Release Publishing Maintenance Releases GitLab

Tags: gitlab, semantic-release

I am in a pickle.

I am following this exact documentation [Releasing a bug fix for version 1.0.x users](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/HEAD/docs/recipes/release-workflow/maintenance-releases.md#releasing-a-bug-fix-for-version-10x-users) for a hotfix in a previous version.

I used the `git checkout -b 1.13.6 v1.13.5` in my case to create a new branch named `1.13.6` from the version `1.13.5`.

Then I updated my `.releaserc.json` file as so:

```json
{
  "branches": [
    "+([0-9])?(.{+([0-9]),x}).x",
    "main"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
    "@semantic-release/gitlab",
    "@semantic-release/npm",
    [
      "@semantic-release/git",
      {
        "assets": [
          "package.json"
        ],
        "message": "chore(release): ${nextRelease.version} [skip ci]\n\n${nextRelease.notes}"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Still, I am getting the annoying `[semantic-release] › ℹ  This test run was triggered on the branch 1.13.6, while semantic-release is configured to only publish from main, therefore a new version won’t be published.` error.

I am using

```json
"@semantic-release/git": "^10.0.1",
"@semantic-release/gitlab": "^12.0.0",
"@semantic-release/npm": "^9.0.2",
"semantic-release": "^23.0.2",
```

I even tried the range writing style within the branched array but this also didn't change anything.

The semantic-release is working flawlessly in the main branch.

What am I missing?